# trapping unhandled exceptions in .NET excel addins (XLL)?

Tags: c#, excel, exception

I am trying to attach a unhandled exception handler for .NET excel addin. The problem is the exception handler is never called.

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException doesn't work - never fires the event.

Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException can't be used as Application is null in the excel addin code.

how do you wire an unhandled exception handler then?

Comment: An XLL is an old style add-in that is based on unmanaged code.  Yes, UnhandledException won't necessarily run when unmanaged code blows up.  Excel would step in first.

Comment: But its not the unmanaged code that blows up.. its the .NET code within the addin that throws an exception. why can't that be trapped anywhere?

Comment: What type of add-in is this? Is it an `IDTExtensibility2`-based add-in or was it built using VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office) using one of the project templates in VS 2005/2008/2010? XLL add-ins are strictly *unmanaged* so this can't be the type of add-in you're running.

Comment: "But its not the unmanaged code that blows up.. its the .NET code within the addin that throws an exception. why can't that be trapped anywhere" <-- The unmanaged exception *is* being handled - by Excel. If you want to handle it, you must intercept the exception *before* it reaches Excel. Attempting to trap the 'AppDomain.UnhandledException' will not work, because it's never going to be unhandled. You need to put exception handlers around all your entry points, e.g., interface implementations, such as 'IDTExtensibility2.OnStartup'; CommandBarControl event handlers; RibbonCallback methods; etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might not be able to, since the application is actually an unmanaged application. You might have to just put try/catch blocks around flaky areas.

Comment: Correct. Since Excel is the caller, it is up to Excel to handle the Exception or not. If Excel handle's it, then there is no unhandled exception. If Excel does not handle it, then Excel crashes. It's that simple. Either way, the managed code execution ends at the COM Interop barrier. The key is not so much to surround all "flaky areas", but to use error handling around all entry points where Excel calls your code.

Comment: Only issue is if you use background threads, and Async libraries. Not a pretty sight!

Comment: @pradeep I found this very helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115030/catch-c-sharp-wpf-unhandled-exception-in-word-add-in-before-microsoft-displays-e

Answer (score 0):

From a user defined function in your XLL you have to trap the exceptions.  You should be using a catch handler to catch everything. It's a code smell but make sure any logging or other processing of the error within the catch doesn't throw by wrapping that with an empty catch handler.

Same from the UI thread for any ribbon event handlers.

If you create your own window any exceptions you leak there will crash excel.  If you're using a WPF window then you can set up a global handler off the dispatcher during the connection of the addin.

Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.UnhandledException += CurrentDispatcher_UnhandledException;

Excel is finicky at best so treat her like [dottie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZc4IBy0pSY)